# Search for elements in a List of Lists in python

Tags: python, list, search, indexing

I'm working on a code in Python. The code should read a textdocument with over 2 million rows. Every row contains 3 numbers. I already wrote a code to store the 3 numbers in 3 different variables. These Variables are stored to one List called "Point". After that i attached the list "Point" to an another list, called "Coordinates".

Now i want to search for specific points. The search algorithm should only scan the first 2 index numbers, because the last number is only for hight measurement.

Does anyone has an idea, how i can realise this?

Thank you very much!

I couldn't try anything because i don't know how this is possible :(

Comment: Please show the code you're working on. Can you show part of the input document?

Comment: Without knowing more about how you want to use the data it is a little hard to advise you, but I think conceptually if you have "a lot" of 3d coordinates and want to search for the existence of them based on the first two dimensions, I would create a dictionary (using setdefault()) with a key of a tuple of those two measures and a value of the third or perhaps a value of a tuple of all three

Answer (score 0):

I generally don't answer questions with no attempt in them. But if you truly can't get started, this is a basic approach:

```
looking_for = (100,100)

for point in coordinates:
   if point[0] == looking_for[0] and point[1] == looking_for[1]:
       print(f"the point is: {point}")
```

Comment: This can be simplified to `if point[0:2] == looking_for:`, but yours is probably better for someone who can't get started.